# Annex data in r

Tags: r

I am trying to carry out following operation in R

I have different series of data,

series 1: 75, 56, 100, 23, 38, 40    series 2: 60, 18, 86, 100, 44

I would like to annex these data. To do so, I have to multiply series 1 by 1.5 to make last data of series 1 (40) match with the first data of the second series (60) (40*1.5=60)

Same way I would like to match many different series, but for other series I will need to multiply by other numbers. For another series i.e Series1: ...20 ; Series 2: 80... I would have to multiply it by 4.

How can I carry out such an operation to many series in many data frames?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Given two vectors `x` and `y`, the function `f(x,y)` below will convert `x` the way you desire.

```
f <- function(x,y) x*(y[1]/x[length(x)])
```

Usage:

```
x = c(75,56,100,23,38,40)
y = c(60,18,86,100,44)

f(x,y)
```

Output:

```
[1] 112.5  84.0 150.0  34.5  57.0  60.0
```

However, how this approach gets applied to "many series in many data frames" depends on the actual structure you have, and what type of output you want.